# Navbar in twitter-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

There is a navigation menu as below and I want all the items in 1 line instead of 2 lines. How do I fix this?

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- navbar-brand is hidden on larger screens, but visible when the menu is collapsed -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Narma Consultancy</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="service.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="client.html">Clients</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="resource.html">Resources</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="vacancy.html">Vacancy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: It's all on one line for me. Perhaps you have some styles that are conflicting with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set width for tags li and use float left for custom it